# How to output an Array as JSON?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, json

I have the following:

```
@array.inspect
["x1", "x2", "adad"]
```

I would like to be able to format that to:

```
client.send_message(s, m, {:id => "x1", :id => "x2", :id => "adad" })
client.send_message(s, m, ???????)
```

How can I have the @array output in the ??????? space as a ids?

Thanks

Comment: The keys of a hash are unique. You'll end up with only one of those values for `:id` if you try this. Are you sure you aren't asking for a list of IDs instead?

Comment: That's probably true but that's the way the LinkedIn gem takes it. Any ideas on how I can format the array into that type of output?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`{:id => "x1", :id => "x2", :id => "adad" }` is not a valid hash since you have a key collision

it should look like:

```
{
  "ids": ["x1", "x2", "x3"]
}
```

Update:

```
@a = ["x1", "x2", "adad"]
@b = @a.map { |e| {:id => e} }
```

Then you can do `b.to_json`, assuming you have done `require "json"` already

Comment: That's probably true but that's the way the LinkedIn gem takes it. Any ideas on how I can format the array into that type of output?

Comment: Could you provide an example?

Comment: Sure thing, what kind of example?

Comment: Please take a look here: https://github.com/pengwynn/linkedin/pull/83#issuecomment-3174282

Comment: They have `[{:id => 1234},{:id => 5678}]`, you have {:id => "x1", :id => "x2" }`. Theirs is an array or hashes, yours is a malformed hash.

Comment: Can you suggest how to form that array?

Answer (score 2):

Well ordinarily you could do something like this:

```
Hash[@array.collect{|i| [:id, i]}]
```

But that will result in {:id => "adad"} because the first element will punch all the rest: hashes in ruby have unique keys. So I don't think there's a super awesome way to do this offhand.